# Increasing Java's BigInteger performance

Tags: java, biginteger

How to increase performance of Java's Big Integer?

For example, this factorial program:

```
import java.math.*;
class Fac {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigInteger i = BigInteger.ONE;
    for(BigInteger z=BigInteger.valueOf(2);z.compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(99999)) != 0;) {
      i = i.multiply(z);
      z = z.add(BigInteger.ONE);
    }
    System.out.println( i );
  }
}
```

That program completed in `31.5`s

Where's in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gmpxx.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  mpz_class r;
  r = 1;
  for(int z=2;z<99999;++z) {
    r *= mpz_class(z);
  }
  cout << r << endl;
}
```

completed in `1.0`s

And Ruby (for comparison):

```
puts (2...99999).inject(:*)
```

completed in `4.4`s (Ruby) and `32.2`s in JRuby

And also Go (for comparison):

```
package main
import (
 "fmt"
 "math/big"
)
func main() {
  i := big.NewInt(1);
  one := big.NewInt(1)
  for z := big.NewInt(2); z.Cmp(big.NewInt(99999)) < 0;  {
      i.Mul(i,z);
      z.Add(z,one)
  }
  fmt.Println( i );
}
```

completed in `1.6`s and `0.7`s for `MulRange`

**EDIT** As requested:

```
import java.math.*;
class F2 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigInteger i = BigInteger.ONE, r = BigInteger.valueOf(2);
    for(int z=2; z<99999 ; ++z) {
      i = i.multiply(r);
      r = r.add(BigInteger.ONE);
    }
    System.out.println( i );
  }
}
```

runtime duration: `31.4` s

**EDIT 2** for those who still think that the first and second java code is unfair..

```
import java.math.*;
class F3 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigInteger i = BigInteger.ONE;
    for(int z=2; z<99999 ; ++z) {
      i = i.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(z));
    }
    System.out.println( i );
  }
}
```

completed in `31.1`s

**EDIT 3** @OldCurmudgeon comment:

```
import java.math.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;
class F4 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      Constructor<?> Bignum = Class.forName("java.math.MutableBigInteger").getDeclaredConstructor(int.class);
      Bignum.setAccessible(true);
      Object i = Bignum.newInstance(1);
      Method m = i.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("mul", new Class[] { int.class, i.getClass()});
      m.setAccessible(true);
      for(int z=2; z<99999 ; ++z) {
        m.invoke(i, z, i);
      }
      System.out.println( i );
    } catch(Exception e) { System.err.println(e); } 
  }
}
```

completed in `23.7`s

**EDIT 4** As stated by @Marco13 the biggest problem was on the string creation not on the BigInteger itself..

- BigInteger: `3.0`s
- MutableBigInteger hack: `10.1`s
- String creation: ~`20`s

Comment: This isn't a completely fair comparison; in Java you're using a `BigInteger` as the loop variable, in C++ you're just using an `int`.

Comment: ^^ A fix would be to start use int. And cache .valueOf or you will create a new BigInteger everytime.

Comment: You could try using [MutableBigInteger](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8583188/823393).

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon, it's about 8 seconds faster, thanks

Comment: You've removed the overhead of the GC of all the previous values but you are still often reallocating an int[]. I tried to tweak your code to pre-allocate a int[50,000] but it doesn't seem to work for me. I'm probably doing it wrong.

Comment: in java 8, edit 2 runs 3.5 seconds. ~3x slower than C++ isn't so bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The computation itself should not take so long. The **string creation** may take a while, however.

This program (Kudos to OldCurmudgeon and https://stackoverflow.com/a/8583188/823393 ) takes approximately 3.9 seconds on a Core I7, 3GHz, Java 7/21, when started with `-Xmx1000m -sever`:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class FastBigInteger
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Class<?> c = Class.forName("java.math.MutableBigInteger");
            Constructor<?> con = c.getDeclaredConstructor(int.class);
            con.setAccessible(true);
            Object i = con.newInstance(1);
            Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("mul", new Class[] { int.class, c });
            m.setAccessible(true);
            long before = System.nanoTime();
            for (int z = 2; z < 99999; ++z)
            {
                m.invoke(i, z, i);
            }
            long after = System.nanoTime();
            System.out.println("Duration "+(after-before)/1e9);

            String s = i.toString();
            int n = s.length();
            int lineWidth = 200;
            for (int j=0; j<n; j+=lineWidth)
            {
                int j0 = j;
                int j1 = Math.min(s.length(), j+lineWidth);
                System.out.println(s.substring(j0, j1));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

After printing the duration for the actual computation, it takes quite a while until it finished creating the string, but this should hardly be taken into account here.

This is still **not a sensible benchmark**, but shows that there is at least no problem with the computation itself.

But admittedly, when using only `BigInteger` instead of this `MutableBigInteger` hack, it takes appx. 15 seconds, which is rather poor compared to the C++ implementation.

Comment: you're right, it done in `3.0`s, total time `23.8`s, so the problem would be on the string creation.

Answer (score 4):

Start with:

```
import java.math.*;
class Fac {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigInteger i = BigInteger.ONE;
    BigInteger maxValue = BigInteger.valueOf(99999);

    for(BigInteger z=BigInteger.valueOf(2); z.compareTo(maxValue) != 0;) {
      i = i.multiply(z);
      z = z.add(BigInteger.ONE);
    }

    System.out.println( i );
  }
}
```

.valueOf source

```
1081    public static BigInteger More ...valueOf(long val) {
1082        // If -MAX_CONSTANT < val < MAX_CONSTANT, return stashed constant
1083        if (val == 0)
1084            return ZERO;
1085        if (val > 0 && val <= MAX_CONSTANT)
1086            return posConst[(int) val];
1087        else if (val < 0 && val >= -MAX_CONSTANT)
1088            return negConst[(int) -val];
1089
1090        return new BigInteger(val);
1091    }
```

It will create a new BigInteger everytime since `MAX_CONSTANT` is 16.

---

I think it could go slower because the GC starts to collect some older `BigInteger` instances but anyway you should always use int and long.. here BigInteger is not really needed.

After your last test i think we can be sure it could be caused by the GC.

Comment: Well, it's the GC. For a correct timing you should disable the GC. (since using int in the for is better) Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java

Answer (score 1):

I have some clojure code calculating the 100 000th fibonacci number using big integers. Now this thread is not about clojure but as clojure runs on the JVM and I ran benchmarks on some of the existing big integer implementations I felt a comment here might be valuable.

The algorithm when it is using the JVM BigInteger class (denoted by the xN literal syntax in clojure) looks as follows:

```
(defn fibo [n]
  (loop [i n a 1N b 1N]
    (if (> i 0)
      (recur (dec i) b (+ a b))
      a)))
```

I have re-implemented this using four big integer implementations and I ran benchmarks using the clojure [criterium](https://github.com/hugoduncan/criterium) library which does warm ups and some statistical analysis to try to get to somewhat relevant numbers.

Results on my 2,8 GHz Intel Core i7 macbook:

- [apfloat](http://www.apfloat.org/apfloat_java/) [apint](http://www.apfloat.org/apfloat_java/docs/org/apfloat/Apint.html) class - 964 ms
- jvm [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class - 130 ms
- [jscience](http://jscience.org/) [LargeInteger](http://jscience.org/api/org/jscience/mathematics/number/LargeInteger.html) class - 104 ms
- [huldra](https://github.com/bwakell/Huldra) [BigInt](https://github.com/bwakell/Huldra/blob/master/src/main/java/org/huldra/math/BigInt.java) class - 60 ms

now I realize this is all anecdotal and that we are only measuring addition here, but I would have to say that the huldra catch phrase "Outperforming BigInteger since 2015" seems pretty accurate in this case.

Any comments with pointers to potential candidates for faster big int addition algorithms are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers are related to tune the performance using code.

If you are using java version less than 1.8.0_151, you can tune big integer performance by using the following command options:

```
-XX:+UseMontgomerySquareIntrinsic
-XX:+UseMontgomeryMultiplyIntrinsic
-XX:+UseSquareToLenIntrinsic
-XX:+UseMultiplyToLenIntrinsic
```

After 1.8.0_151, these options are turned on by default.