# Is BigInteger Thread safe?

Tags: java, biginteger

I have a requirement to update a global `BigInteger` value via multiple threads -- is `BigInteger` thread safe?

Comment: Please have a look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890968/what-is-the-purpose-of-java-math-mutablebiginteger

Comment: Whether BigInteger is threadsafe is irrelevant to you as it is immutable. So you have to replace the reference to the BigInteger with another one to update it. And you need to make sure that *you* do that in a thread safe manner.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**[BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)** objects are an representative example of [immutable objects](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=29).
To put it simply:

> Each immutable **object is thread-safe**, but the **reference to it
>   [is not](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/thread-safety-and-immutability.html)**.

For **immutable objects** the state is fixed for an entire lifetime. Because there is no option to change it therefore each "change" operation is equivalent to replacement by a new object. So after series of modifications performed parallely by N threads on a specific reference the result value is hard to predict (some updates could be lost - unnoticed).
The same story is with [Integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) class. To overcome that limitation **[AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html)** class was introduced to [JDK5](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/relnotes/features.html).
Unfortunately there is no "*AtomicBigInteger*" class in JDK. The alternate solution is to wrap an object instance with **[AtomicReference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html)** - which works as a proxy that makes all operations synchronised and atomic.

I propose a following compact solution that requires JDK 8:

```
final AtomicReference<BigInteger> valueHolder = new AtomicReference(BigInteger.ZERO);
```

Using this approach any method provided by **BigInteger** could be restated as a **lambda expression**, e.g.:

```
valueHolder.updateAndGet(x -> x.add(BigInteger.valueOf(10)));
```

To check if the solution is correct you may use this code snippet that sums up all integers lower than 100 using parallel streams (it is multithread operation):

```
IntStream.range(0, 100).parallel()
        .forEach(i -> valueHolder.updateAndGet(x -> x.add(BigInteger.valueOf(i))));
```

Comment: That doesn't make it thread safe by itself as there are no atomic arithmetic operations on AtomicReference. You can use compareAndSet to implement a spinning approach but you would need to expand your answer for that. Or if you want to suggest using jdk1.8 functionality you should also add that to your answer.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Thanks for an advice. I just improved code sample.

Comment: Worked great. I was trying to sum every number in a list with the possible sum exceeding the int/long restrictions, so I tweaked the code and used:

`final AtomicReference<BigInteger> bsum = new AtomicReference<BigInteger>(BigInteger.ZERO);
        Arrays.asList(numbers).forEach(number -> {bsum.set(bsum.get().add(new BigInteger(number)));});`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot update BigInteger, read javadoc, it's *Immutable arbitrary-precision integers.*.  To update a BigInteger field you will need to replace it with a new BigInteger, like this

```
...
bigInteger = bigInteger.add(value);
...
```

and this will require synchronization otherwise two things may happen:

1. one thread changed the value but other threads do not see the change
2. two or more threads are adding simultaneously but some addings are lost.

Answer (score 1):

[`java.math.BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) is immutable and as such it is safe for access by multiple threads.

Side-note: [Thread-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety) is a term that deals with multiple threads accessing a *piece of code* (not just a variable).

Comment: Be careful about connecting "thread safety" with "code" when you're talking to noobs.  When we talk about the "thread safety" of some body of code (e.g., a Java class), we are talking about what can happen to the _data_ that the code operates on in a multi-threaded environment.  A lot of noobs talk about "synchronized methods", and "synchronized blocks", without ever understanding that it's the data that need protection.

Comment: @jameslarge the code itself is obviously stateless unless it's not immutable. I didn't run into "self modifying code" for a long time now... :)

Answer (score 0):

The BigInteger is thread safe.
But you want update it,you should use code like this:

```
private BigInteger bigInteger = BigInteger.ONE;

public void add(BigInteger plus) {
    bigInteger = bigInteger.add(plus);
}
```

so synchronize is necessary.

Comment: Source documentation showing that BigInteger is threadsafe (or a code sample that proves it) would greatly enhance this answer.  Welcome to Stack Overfllow!

Answer (score 0):

> [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) : **Immutable** arbitrary-precision integers.
>
> [Immutable Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html) : An object is considered immutable if its **state cannot change after it is constructed**. Maximum reliance on immutable objects is widely accepted as a **sound strategy for creating simple, reliable code**.

**This mean BigInteger is thread-safe.**